# Consuming Webservice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services

Now, i want to use service from http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx to get weather by javascript. I try this code:

```
var wsUrl = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: wsUrl,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapRequest,
    success: processSuccess,
    error: processError
});

        });
    });

function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
    if (status == "success")
        $("#response").text($(req.responseXML).find("GetWeatherResult").text());
}

function processError(data, status, req) {
    alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    // alert("Error");
}
```

Comment: var soapRequest =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CityName>' + $("#txtName1").val() + '</CityName>
      <CountryName>' + $("#txtName2").val() + '</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'

Comment: In what way is this not working?  Please describe the problem.  Also, code should be placed in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Everything @David said, and what's with the extra `});`s? Please check your code again, I think you missed some lines prior to `var wsUrl ...`.

Comment: You can check in here: https://gist.github.com/phuong1492/565be0e13df60d1ecaef

Comment: @Krumia : When i run this file HTML has error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. " i can't fix it...

Comment: @bloodseeker: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy